# How to perform a select if duplicates do not exist?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I'm looking for the *best* possible way to select an object if *no duplicates exists*.

I have a method that is duplicating an array of objects. But there's no need to duplicate them  if a duplicate already exists.

How can I initially select my array of not-yet-duplicated objects in a lightweight way via mysql2?

Comment: objects = database rows? If so, do a self join, group by the duplicated column and having count = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(name_of_col) From table_name
GROUP BY name_of_col 
HAVING COUNT(name_of_col) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT object FROM table GROUP BY object HAVING count(*)=1
```